# Web API controller returning boolean

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API where one of the methods in a controller return true or false when validating user id which is a string of numbers. I do no have an actual database yet, so I sort of mocked up the set of values in the repository.

Below is my code:

My repository class:

```
 public class myRepository
{
      public myClasses.Employee[] GetAllEmployees()
        {

            return new myClasses.Employee[]
            {
                new myClasses.Employee 
                {
                    empId="111111",
                    empFName = "Jane",
                    empLName="Doe"
                },
                new myClasses.Employee 
                {
                    empId="222222",
                    empFName = "John",
                    empLName="Doe"
                }
           };

      }

        public bool VerifyEmployeeId(string id)
        {

            myClasses.Employee[] emp = new myClasses.Employee[]
            {
                new myClasses.Employee 
                {
                    empId="111111",
                    empFName = "Jane",
                    empLName="Doe"
                },
                new myClasses.Employee 
                {
                    empId="222222",
                    empFName = "John",
                    empLName="Doe"
                }
           };

            for (var i = 0; i <= emp.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (emp[i].empId == id)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
   }
```

and my model class:

```
public class myClasses
{

    public class Employee
    {
        public string empId { get; set; }
        public string empFName { get; set; }
        public string empLName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and here is my controller:

```
 public class myClassesController : ApiController
{
     private myRepository empRepository;

    public myClassesController()
    {

        this.empRepository = new myRepository();
    }


     public myClasses.Employee[] GetEmployees()
    {
        return empRepository.GetAllEmployees();
    }

 public bool VerifyEmployee(string id)
    {
        return empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(string id);
    }

}
```

Now when i compile it I get an error:

```
} expected
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   
; expected
```

in line

```
return empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(string id);
```

of my controller.

My question is using boolean the best way to return Success or Failure from Web API method or is there a better way? and also why am I getting this error. I am new to Web API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error is caused by this;

```
return empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(string id);
```

You should rewrite to:

```
return empRepository.VerifyEmployeeId(id);
```

You don't have you specify the type of the argument when calling a function.

About returning true or false; if you intend to only check whether the employee is valid or not, I should leave it this way. If you plan to use that employee data more you could rewrite that function so it returns the actual employee itself, and return 404: Not Found when the Employee is not found for instance.

Comment: OMG I am having a bad day:(